# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded | ExtJs

Tags: asp.net, extjs

In chrome version 80.0.. 64bit machine, I get an error that Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Ext.Element.getWidth()

The web application was working fine since 2015 with no issues in any machine. I have read that this could be caused due to an infinite loop.

There is a code for 100% slider in the application.

```
resize: function () {
    if(this.slider) this.slider.setWidth(this.getWidth() - 2);
    this.doLayout();
}
```

[image: Error Stack]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the slider component to occupy 100% of the width, it is better to use [layout](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.layout.Layout) ([fit](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Fit) if if the slider is an only child, [vbox](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.VBox) if other components are located under it).

If you need help with your `resize` handler, please tell me the version of extjs and show whole error stack.

Comment: all stack. in expanded state, please